# Biadjoint and exact functors whose "tops" are inverse.

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I'm curious if there is much we can say about the following general situation.

---

Suppose that we have a pair of biadjoint exact functors $F : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$, and $G: \mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{A}$, with the property that for all $A \in \operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{A})$, and $B \in \operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{B})$, there exists $C^{\mathcal{A}}_{A,B} \in \operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{A})$ and $C^{\mathcal{B}}_{A,B} \in \operatorname{Obj}(\mathcal{B})$ fitting into short exact sequences

$$
0 \to C^{\mathcal{B}}_{A,B} \to F(A) \to B \to 0, \qquad 0 \to C^{\mathcal{A}}_{A,B} \to G(B) \to A \to 0.
$$

---

Notice that if $C^{\mathcal{B}}_{A,B} = C^{\mathcal{A}}_{A,B} = 0$ for all $A$, and $B$, then $F$ and $G$ are quasi-inverse. In this way this property could be viewed as a weakening of quasi-inverse (with exactness/biadjointness thrown in).

I understand this is a bit of a vague question. But any thoughts / references would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what are the maps $F(A)\to B$ and $G(B)\to A$. Do you mean that for all $A,B$ there exist such maps ? That sound weird... Do you have an explicit example in mind ?

Comment: Yes I mean that for all A and B there exists such maps. I don’t have an explicit example in mind for the exact definition. But I have quite an involved example that behaves a little like this, and I formulated this question out of curiosity more than anything.

Comment: I’m thinking about this in terms of representation theory, and here the short exact sequences would be the tops of some sort of filtration

Comment: But I still don't understand : take $A=0$ then for any $B$ you want a short exact sequence $0\to C^{\mathcal B}_{0,B}\to 0\to B\to 0$. This is clearly impossible...

Comment: Ah.I should have spotted that. Thank you!